# How to import an external library project in android studio for IBM MobileFirst project?

Tags: android, android-studio, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to import an external library project into my project in android studio.

My  project is a hybrid project (using IBM MobileFirst), I am using Eclipse to compile but facing the dex 65k limit issue, so I have to use android studio to compile.

I am following this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KA56j2Yk6M
but I dont have the Gradle Script since it is a hybrid application.

Does anyone have experience on how to import an external library project in android studio for IBM MobileFirst project ?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle support is not possible and indeed it will be difficult to get out of the 65k limit issue without it.

What you can do:

1. Use MobileFirst 7.1 which provides now a new application type support as a pure cordova app, so you won't need to use the Hybrid app model
2. Attempt to add ProGuard support which may help in reduce the files thus enabling you to add the library via Eclipse

Comment: May I know what is the difference between pure cordova app and Hybrid app model ? To be specific, my external library is a pdf sdk, I need the pdf sdk for viewing pdf in my app. (Since android doesn't support pdf view function). So I am looking a way to import external library in android studio.

Comment: MFP Hybrid apps bundle cordova inside the app whereas in pure cordova app MFP is a plug-in like any other cordova plug-in.

Comment: I am already using MobileFirst 7.1, but how to build a pure cordova app ?

Comment: Please see the documentation... search for "cordova".

Comment: My project need to import many external library, I think the pure cordova app is not suitable as a solution

Comment: Please read the documentation. A Cordova app still generates a native project to open in Android Studio.

Comment: Is that possible for import external library project in android studio without gradle ?